# look for specific service names (if present in Services.msc and save to a listbox c#

Tags: c#, service, listbox

I'm trying to get a listbox of specific services (that my software uses) and then use buttons to "start" "stop" and "restart" in Visual C#.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

```
Process[] processCollection = Process.GetProcesses();  
private void ButtonOnClick(object seender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Process p in processCollection)  
    {  
        // make sure its a service 1st
        if(!Environment.UserInteractive){ 

        // iterate over processes and stuff into listbox
        var exename = Path.GetFileName(p.MainModule.FileName) 
        listBoxVar.Items.Add(exename);
        }
        // start/restart a process
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(exename);
        Process.Start(startInfo);

        // kill a process 
        p.Kill();
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps :):) 

Just to clear myself, in the (exename) you said, I enter the servicename.exe right? if I have multiple, i had multiple lines of same or can use commas? Can I specify to see if that service is even available? Reason is the client might not have multiple versions installed and each version comes with specific service.

Comment: no, exename retrieves the service exe name and path...it really sounds like you may need more learning b4 you can use my snippet :)